# How to get and extract matched css rules on dom-node?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to know an easy way to get all the css rules and classes on a certain DOM node and the subtree programmatically.

#### Chrome Dev Tools

Inspecting the style of an element in the chrome dev tools returns 2 panels

1. Computed Style
2. Styles

The Styles-Panel has 3 different style categories:

- element.style
- Matched CSS Rules
- inherited from ....

The function `window.getMatchedCSSRules` comes quite close to the panel  Matched CSS Rules in the dev-tools.
I want to iterate over an element and its children and add the matched css rules to a string.

This [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U2LZG/31/) explains and demonstrates the expected and the unwanted result

Example:

```
<a class="one to many">
    <span class="even more">foo</span>
    <span class="way muchMore"> bar</span>
</a>
```

How can i get all the css-classes with the stylerules like this

```
a.one { color: red; }
.to { margin: 2em}
```

And so on. The following function comes quite close to the expected result:

```
// el = a DOM-Node document.getElementById(id);
function getCssText(el) {
    var cssText = "";
    var cssRuleList = window.getMatchedCSSRules(el, '');
    for (var i = 0; i < cssRuleList.length; i++) {
        cssText += cssRuleList[i].cssText + " ";
    }
    return cssText;
}
```

Alexander pointed to this [discussion about window.getMatchedCSSRules() returning null](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=69626)

Does anyone have a plugin or a more sophisticated function for me to retrieve the css classes and the values of a domnode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What prevents you from mouse-selecting and copying (Ctrl-C, whatever) the contents of the "Matched CSS Rules" or "Computed Styles" section in the sidebar (am I missing the task you are trying to solve?)

There's a known issue with pasting the copied contents into well-known HTML-aware text editors (the CSS properties inside rules are rendered as a numbered list, which is actually a bug in the respective editors) but otherwise, if you want to manually grab a copy of all your matched CSS rules/computed style for a DOM element, this workflow should work for you.

#### 3rd party edit

In the comment below it is recommended to use `window.getMatchedCSSRules()`. Using it in Chrome 62 returns this

> VM1395:1 [Deprecation] 'getMatchedCSSRules()' is deprecated. For more
>   help, check
>   https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=437569#c2

The [discussion getMatchedCSSRules  was started in november 2014](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=437569#c2) and contains this bit `getMatchedCSSRules is non-standard and likely to be removed in the coming months. Relying on it is bad for cross-browser interop since major browsers like Firefox and IE won't be supported.` It seems that M63 will start to remove it.

An alternative might be to use [CSS Object Model (CSSOM)](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/)

Comment: This would be possible but would require to copy and paste a lot. If there was a way to solve this by script it could be used on any site.

Comment: Ah, you want to do that programmatically in a uniform way... You have `window.getMatchedCSSRules()` but it doesn't always return what you need. Have a look at [this Chromium issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=69626) (comment #7) for a workaround.

Comment: Hi Alexander, i took a look at [the discussion](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=69626#c3) about the [InspectorCSSAgent](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/inspector/InspectorCSSAgent.cpp?rev=83962#L204) and the [DOMWindow](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/page/DOMWindow.cpp?rev=75276#L1304). It seems to me that your comment is spot on. Unfortunately i do not know how to [load the content of all remote css files and append it to the document as a <style>](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=69626#c7)

Comment: This can be accomplished in two steps. First, you collect all `<link rel="stylesheet">` elements and get their `href` attribute values. This way you learn all the external stylesheet resources (you need to complete relative URLs using the main document's base URL.) Next, you load all these stylesheets using XHR in the order they are referenced by the `<link>` tags, concatenate their contents, create a `<style>` element, set its `textContent` to the resulting concatenated string, and append to, say, `document.body`. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

In the 'Elements' tab of the dev tools in chrome, if you select any particular node, it displays all the matched Style rules in the panel to the right (both individually matched rules, and an overall computed style for the node).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sorry for not being more clear in my question. I would like to be able to "export" the displayed "matched css rules" instead of looking up each individually.